# Show snackbar from scaffold inside onPressed callback on Floating Action Button

Tags: flutter

I am trying to call

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  content: Text("Snack text"),
));
```

inside `onPressed` of `floatingActionButton` of scaffold.

I get this error

```
I/flutter (18613): Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
I/flutter (18613): No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to 
....
```

And it points to a solution when you call `Scaffold.of(context)` inside a body.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html

But the same solution doesnt work if you call it inside onPressed of `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: Add the code of the Widget where scaffold and FloatingActionButton is defined.

Comment: Please post the complete code for better understanding

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UPDATE: The second solution is better than this solution.

You should put the floatingActionButton widget in a Builder Widget. 
The following code should work:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          Scaffold
              .of(context)
              .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('Hello!')));
        });
      }),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new MySwitch(
              value: _switchValue,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                if (value != _switchValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _switchValue = value;
                  });
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I will try your code. I tried Builder myself but it didnt work. Let me try again

Comment: this answer is more reliable. at least for beginners and as per flutter documentation

Comment: Didn't work for me either. The solution with the Scaffold.key is more reliable and easier, I think. It avoids having to pass around the context variable...

Comment: I think you all are right, the solution from Vinoth Kumar and CodeChimp is better than mine.

Answer (score 15):

Add a Globalkey of the Scaffold state and use that
to display snack bar as below,

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState;

Scaffold {
key: scaffoldState,
....


scaffoldState.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('Hello!')));
```

Comment: Perfect answer +1

Comment: Be sure to initialize scaffoldState. For example scaffoldState = GlobalKey()

Answer (score 2):

This is even simpler. **Tried it.** Create the FloatingActionButton as a **separate Stateless Widget.** **Call this Stateless Widget from the Scaffold.**

```
class Abc extends StatelessWidget
{
   Widget build(BuildContext context)
   {
      return Scaffold(
         appBar:AppBar(title:Text("Long List View")),
         body:SomeOtherWidget(),
         floatingActionButton:MyFAB()  
      );
   }
}

class MyFAB extends StatelessWidget
{
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
       return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed:(){
                showSnackBarHandler(context);
            },
            child:Icon(Icons.add),
            tooltip:"Press to Add More"
       );
    }
}

void showSnackBarHandler(BuildContext context){

var snackBar = SnackBar(
    content:Text("Hello")
);

Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);

}
```