# Common Snackbar does not show

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a Common class for SnackBar,

```
class MySnackBar extends StatelessWidget {
  String message;
  int duration;
  BuildContext context;
  MySnackBar(BuildContext context,String message, int duration) {
    this.message = message;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _showSnackBar(this.context, message, duration);
  }

  Widget _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message, int duration) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      duration: Duration(seconds: duration),
    ));
  }
}
```

I am calling this class from my other widget like this,

```
 MySnackBar(
  context,
  _postDetailsModel
    .language.postScreen.bookmarkOwnMessage,
     3);
```

But it neither displays snackbar nor it throws an error. Can anyone tell me what I am missing or is there is a way to create common snackbar class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should directly use this :

```dart
void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message, int duration) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      duration: Duration(seconds: duration),
    ));
  }
```

as a method and not as a Widget.

Comment: I have tried this already, it throws `Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.`

Comment: Well there is plenty of threads about it, for exemple see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304732/10122791) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452277/10122791)

Comment: But then I will have to pass a scafoldkey every time in the common widget, right? that's kind of kill the purpose. But for now, I think that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Or as mentioned in the first link, you use a builder to provide a context which contains a Scaffold, it depends how you want to use your snackbar.
Personnaly, I switched to Flushbar to avoid those scaffold key problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flushbar https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

create customFlushBar

```
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Flushbar customFlushBar(BuildContext context,String text){
  return Flushbar(
    flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
    message: text,
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.info_outline,
      size: 28.0,
      color: Colors.blue[300],
    ),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.blue[300],
  )..show(context);
}
```

you can called like this:

```
customFlushBar(context, 'Sign in failed');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a solution that does not have any 3rd party library.